# How to find a value up to some decimal point?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with thousand of rows like:

```
name,post
x1,25.84
x2,51.0634699001
x3,73.01
x4,72.0
x5,79.0
x6,75.9
x7,95.29
x8,93.55
x9,93.7
x10,10.0
x11,93.99
```

I am trying to write a python code, possibly something with pandas maybe that will pick up only the post values ending with .0 The desired output in this case is

```
name,post
x4,72.0
x5,79.0
x10,10.0
```

not showing x2 and x3 because after 0 other numbers exist. I tried this but not working:

```
df['zeros'] = df['post'].str.extract('([.0]*[,.][.0]*)')
```

Comment: If you have floats, you cannot

Answer (score 0):

If you have floats, this is not possible.

Assuming you have strings, use [`str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
out = df[df['post'].str.endswith('0')]
```

If you want to ensure matching a decimal ending in `0` (again, with a string as input), use:

To allow integers without decimal part (10)

```
out = df[df['post'].str.fullmatch(r'\d+(\.\d*0)?')]
```

To forbid integers without decimal part:

```
out = df[df['post'].str.fullmatch(r'\d+(\.\d*0)')]
```

Output:

```
  name  post
3   x4  72.0
4   x5  79.0
9  x10  10.0
```

Comment: This will as well consider 72.0000010 as valid

Comment: @amirhm this seems to be wanted, no? Else this would mean checking for an integer (which you could do with `s = df['post'].astype(float) ; df[s.eq(s.astype(int))]`)

Comment: to me it looked like something like this he is asking:    df[df['post'].astype(int)  == df['post'] ]

Comment: yes, exactly, Iike the expression you have in edited comment.